# Why cv-qualification for a reference is ill-formed?

Tags: c++

As per [dcl.ref/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.ref#1):

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers
>   are introduced through the use of a typedef-name

So I've tried:

```
int a = 1;
int& const r1 = a;
```

And got the error:

```
error: 'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'int&'
```

which is expected to prompt the diagnostic message.

However, I wanted to know *why* is it prohibited.

Is it only to prevent the accident of writing the code above when programmer actually means:

```
const int& r1 = a; // const reference to int
```

**MAIN QUESTION**
2) Or is there some deeper reason / practical examples why disallowing it is indeed beneficial?

Any thoughts?

Comment: If something is meaningless, it is almost always beneficial to make it a compile error. It's meaningless, so there's no reason to write it, which means that writing it is likely to be a mistake

Comment: Just to add on to Justin's comment; it is meaningless because references are always constant i.e. they always point to the same thing.

Comment: @Justin, makes sense. I agree it's already redundant since references are already `const` so no need to add `const`-qualifier.

Comment: @andrew.punnett, thanks. I agree. but would emphasize *refer* to instead of *point* to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CV-qualifiers are valid for pointers:

```
int a;
int * const p = &a;
```

This applies to the pointer itself, not what it points to.

But since you can't change a reference after definition, there's no point in adding CV-Qs to references.